# "Cold Turkey Blocker" lock CLI (command line) is not working

Tags: command-line, windows-11, command-line-arguments, application-launch

I am trying to run the command:
[The “Cold Turkey Blocker” **lock** CLI](https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/#part-commands:%7E:text=%5B%2Dstart%20%22Block%20Name%22%20%2Dlock%20X%5D) (command line) is not working.

```
"C:\Program Files\Cold Turkey\Cold Turkey Blocker.exe" -start "Block" -lock 2
```

[The command is as shown in the application documents:](https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/#part-commands:%7E:text=%5B%2Dstart%20%22Block%20Name%22%20%2Dlock%20X%5D)
[https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/#part-commands:~:text=%5B%2Dstart%20%22Block%20Name%22%20%2Dlock%20X%5D](https://getcoldturkey.com/support/user-guide/#part-commands:%7E:text=%5B%2Dstart%20%22Block%20Name%22%20%2Dlock%20X%5D)

### There are two possible scenarios:

### First, When the “Cold Turkey Blocker” is open:

I tried to run the command; The block does not activate (useless) without showing any errors on the terminal.
[image: terminal shows no error, but no block is activated]
After contacting the developer, he told me to force kill the “Cold Turkey Blocker.exe”. As the CLI part does not work while the “Cold Turkey Blocker.exe” application is in foreground.
Something like that:

```
taskkill /IM "Cold Turkey Blocker.exe" /F & "C:\Program Files\Cold Turkey\Cold Turkey Blocker.exe" -start "Block" -lock 2
```

### Second, When the “Cold Turkey Blocker” is closed/killed (using the script mentioned above):

When I run the lock command, The block does not activate, then I receive the error (check the image below):

```
New line terminal output, then Error: Invalid Block Name
```

[image: Invalid Block Name]

Can anyone reproduce the issue I'm experiencing?